# CakePHP 1.3 Ajax pagination using JQuery helper

Tags: ajax, cakephp, jquery, pagination

I am building a cake application using cake 1.3 and JS helper using JQuery. I followed the ajax pagination tutorial properly from [cake's 1.3 tutorial](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1600/Ajax-Pagination) however there is some issue. First page loads fine and when I click on pagination links, action is performed using Ajax however the next page is empty and then no other pagination link works (nothing happens on click). I guess it's a pagination chaining issue however I am following the steps needed to chain the pages properly as mentioned in above tutorial.

One difference in my case is that I am not using the layout div's ID, instead I am using a div from view inside which I am looping through the data. This div contains the paginator options and pagination links so I guess it shouldn't be an issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the page you linked, there's a section that reads:

> You then create all the links as needed for your pagination features. Since the JsHelper automatically buffers all generated script content to reduce the number of  tags in your source code you must call write the buffer out. At the bottom of your view file. Be sure to include:
>
> `echo $this->Js->writeBuffer();`
>
> If you omit this you will not be able to chain ajax pagination links. When you write the buffer, it is also cleared, so you don't have worry about the same Javascript being output twice.

This matches your symptoms pretty closely; did you remember to follow this step?